# Android GoogleMaps

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api

Хочу создать кнопку, которая создаёт изначально перетаскиваемый маркер. Ничего не приходит в голову, что бы ни пробовал, постоянно создается обычный маркер.

```
binding.buttonCreateMarker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        getDeviceLocation();
        gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude())).draggable(true));
    }
});
```

}